# Order items in MongoDB according to the size of an array with MongoMapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'd like to select a collection of items ordered based on the number of items within an array. Hopefully the following example will clarify my rather poor explanation:

```
class Thing
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :tags, Array
end
```

I'd like to retrieve all `Thing`s ordered from those with the most tags to those with the least. The tags in this example are simply strings within the tags array. Basically I want something which means the same as this (but works):

```
Thing.all(:order => 'tags.count desc')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core server currently doesn't support computing the size of an array and then sorting by that. I think that your best bet for the moment would be to cache the array size on your own, and add an index on that field.

```
class Thing
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name,     String
  key :tags,     Array
  key :tag_size, Integer, :default => 0, :index => true
end
```

Then just add a callback to your model that updates tag_size on save.

If this is a feature you'd like to see in the core server, you can add a case here:

http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER

Comment: Ah, fair enough - I assumed it was supported. Thanks for the alternative suggestion though, that does sound like my best bet.